# Partitioning table that is typically only inserted to in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, partitioning

I have a table that is having approximately 450,000 records per month going into it. It is an audit table of sorts that tracks changes to other tables in the database. That is, inserts, updates and deletes of records. Typically this table is not queried (perhaps only 2-3 times per month to examine how data in other tables changed and under very specific circumstances)

It has been put to me that we should consider partitioning this table to help improve database performance. If the table is only being inserted to 99.9% of the time and rarely queried, would there be any tangible benefit to this partitioning this table?

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: Partitioning is NOT a performance tool. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/

Comment: @JohnConde sorry. that was clearly a mistake

Comment: @SeanLange - i had discovered that link myself in my research. i'm not trying to use it as a performance tool. everything I've read seems to point to the general observation that partitioning in the right circumstances will help with queries etc. are you saying the answer here is "no"?

Comment: I am saying that partitioning only because you want to improve performance is very likely that you would be partitioning for the wrong reason. It brings a lot of baggage with it. I would ask if you are only querying this table 2-3 times a month for data analysis why are you overly worried about performance?

Comment: @SeanLange thanks - that's a helpful line of thinking. we have to maintain this table - personally I don't think partitioning is going to help us here, but it had been put to be by someone more experienced in this area that since we insert an audit record each time that something else happens in our db, we would benefit in some way from partitioning. since we rarely query it, I asked the question if there was a tangible benefit to partitioning (and all the work that would involve) - it would appear for us, the answer is no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the table is only being inserted to 99.9% of the time and rarely
>   queried, would there be any tangible benefit to this partitioning this
>   table?

Partitioning is mostly a manageability feature. I would expect no difference in insert performance with or without able partitioning. For `SELECT` queries, partitioning may improve performance of large scans if partitions can be eliminated (i.e. partitioning column specified in `WHERE` clause, but indexing and query tuning is usually the key to performance.

Partitioning can improve performance of purge operations. For example, you could use a monthly sliding window to purge an entire month of data at once rather than individual row deletes. I don't know if that's with the trouble with only 450K rows/month, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get fast access to your recent data.
Add date column as first column in primary key clustered instead of partioning